# A word meaning "communicating one idea" (Mono-<something>-ic?)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking to see if there is a word to describe "communicating one thought". I imagine it would be something like "Mono--ic". This is how I am attempting to use it:

"Instead of using a choropleth map, which is mono--ic, we should use a more dynamic map which displays multiple statistics simultaneously."

For those who don't know, a choropleth map is a map with solid colors which correspond to a single value. E.g. A red county might mean it's population is primarily republican.

Which I am trying to communicate is that we should use a map which does not communicate a single thought per area - rather a map that communicates multiple aspects at the same time.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

-Kivak

Comment: Definitely like that! However, a choropleth map is monothematic to begin with. I'm thinking more in terms of conveying only one piece of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be  referring to [Monothematic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monothematic): adj.

> Having only one theme.